# Setting threshold on max number of classes selected/activated on click on multiple divs/id's

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been working on a skill tree 'persay' and I ran into an interesting problem.

I have my code setup to allow a user to click a talent to show that particular talent has been selected up to a max number of 4 talents total. Once you have selected 4 talents you have to deselect a talent to select a different one.

My problem comes when I duplicate the talent tree for a second talent tree on the same page(for a second hero/class essentially or a second party member out of your party). I can't figure out how to make the same 'threshold of a max of 4 talents' on other skill trees standalone. What happens is that they all share the same threshold across all trees. I have tried making separate id's each and even changing the variable names within each function.

```js
var skillTotal = 0;
var skillSelected = 0;

$( "#selectable01>li.skill-slot" ).bind( "click", function ( e ) {
    var threshold = 4;
        var price = 1;
        if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
                skillTotal = skillTotal - 1;
                skillSelected--;
                $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        }
        else if (price + skillTotal <= threshold) {
                skillTotal = skillTotal + price;
                skillSelected++;
                $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        }
});

$( "#selectable02>li.skill-slot" ).bind( "click", function ( e ) {
    var threshold = 4;
        var price = 1;
        if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
                skillTotal = skillTotal - 1;
                skillSelected--;
                $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        }
        else if (price + skillTotal <= threshold) {
                skillTotal = skillTotal + price;
                skillSelected++;
                $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        }
});

/* NOT USING THIS CURRENTLY 
$( "#campSelectable>li.camp-slot" ).bind( "click", function ( e ) {
    var campThreshold = 3;
        var campPrice = 1;
        if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
                campTotal = campTotal - campPrice;
                selectedCamp--;
                $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        }
        else if (campPrice + campTotal <= campThreshold) {
                campTotal = campTotal + campPrice;
                selectedCamp++;
                $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        }
}); */
```

```css
.skill-slot, .camp-slot{
  border:2px solid black;
  width:100px;
  margin: 5px;
  opacity: .4;
}

.skill-slot:hover, .camp-slot:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.raffle-slot.taken{
  background:red;
}
.selected{
  background: rgb(255, 128, 128);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="calc">
<ol class="roster" id="selectable01">
<li class="skill-slot">1</li>
<li class="skill-slot">2</li>
<li class="skill-slot">3</li>
<li class="skill-slot">4</li>
<li class="skill-slot">5</li>
<li class="skill-slot">6</li>
<li class="skill-slot">7</li>
</ol>

<ol class="roster" id="selectable02">
<li class="skill-slot">1</li>
<li class="skill-slot">2</li>
<li class="skill-slot">3</li>
<li class="skill-slot">4</li>
<li class="skill-slot">5</li>
<li class="skill-slot">6</li>
<li class="skill-slot">7</li>
</ol>

</div>
```

Here are the things I have tried: 
Initially my identifier was : `$( "#calc>ol>li.skill-slot" ).on` so I began adding additional id's to drill down further and make sure that my functions were targeting specific div's, so I moved to this: `$( "#calc>#selectable01>li.skill-slot" ).on` and `$( "#calc>#selectable02>li.skill-slot" ).on`

The reason I didn't want to target a second ID is because I'll be using templates that are appended to the #calc div effectively replacing the current roster with a new one. I also did this for testing to see if I could resolve the issue by making them their own individual id's, which didn't work.

Comment: Please don't post your code at 3rd party links as they can become bad over time. Post your code right here.

Comment: Thanks Scott, appreciate the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way simpler approach using Event delegation. Toggle `.selected` to either deactivate the current `.skill-slot`, or to activate it if there are less than 4 `.selected.skill-slot`s in this group.

```js
$('#selectable01, #selectable02').on('click', '.skill-slot', function(e){
  if($(this).hasClass('selected') || $('.selected.skill-slot', e.delegateTarget).length < 4){
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
  }
});
```

```css
.skill-slot, .camp-slot{
  border:2px solid black;
  width:100px;
  margin: 5px;
  opacity: .4;
}

.skill-slot:hover, .camp-slot:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.raffle-slot.taken{
  background:red;
}
.selected{
  background: rgb(255, 128, 128);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="calc">
<ol class="roster" id="selectable01">
<li class="skill-slot">1</li>
<li class="skill-slot">2</li>
<li class="skill-slot">3</li>
<li class="skill-slot">4</li>
<li class="skill-slot">5</li>
<li class="skill-slot">6</li>
<li class="skill-slot">7</li>
</ol>

<ol class="roster" id="selectable02">
<li class="skill-slot">1</li>
<li class="skill-slot">2</li>
<li class="skill-slot">3</li>
<li class="skill-slot">4</li>
<li class="skill-slot">5</li>
<li class="skill-slot">6</li>
<li class="skill-slot">7</li>
</ol>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

As you are using global variables for the count and total, this obviously leads to a global limit. To make the limit local to each of the groups, you could use  data attributes of these `ol` elements, so they work independently from each other. With some other little improvements, your code could look like this:

```js
$("#selectable01, #selectable02").data("skillTotal", 0).data("skillSelected", 0);

$("#selectable01>li.skill-slot,#selectable02>li.skill-slot").on("click", function () {
    var threshold = 4, 
        price = 1,
        sign = $(this).hasClass('selected') ? -1: 1,
        $p = $(this).parent(),
        newPrice = $p.data("skillTotal") + sign*price;
    if (newPrice > threshold) return; 
    $p.data("skillTotal", newPrice)
      .data("skillSelected", $p.data("skillSelected") + sign);
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
});
```

```css
.skill-slot, .camp-slot{
  border:2px solid black;
  width:100px;
  margin: 5px;
  opacity: .4;
}

.skill-slot:hover, .camp-slot:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.raffle-slot.taken{
  background:red;
}
.selected{
  background: rgb(255, 128, 128);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="calc">
<ol class="roster" id="selectable01">
<li class="skill-slot">1</li>
<li class="skill-slot">2</li>
<li class="skill-slot">3</li>
<li class="skill-slot">4</li>
<li class="skill-slot">5</li>
<li class="skill-slot">6</li>
<li class="skill-slot">7</li>
</ol>

<ol class="roster" id="selectable02">
<li class="skill-slot">1</li>
<li class="skill-slot">2</li>
<li class="skill-slot">3</li>
<li class="skill-slot">4</li>
<li class="skill-slot">5</li>
<li class="skill-slot">6</li>
<li class="skill-slot">7</li>
</ol>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're storing `skillSelected` outside of the event handlers so each event handler is reading that variable. You might need to get a running total of how many are selected each time the event handler is triggered.

Comment: So I initially thought that too and tried to create those variables inside of the functions, but for some reason those variables inside of the function didn't work? I'm not sure why I can create the variable `var price =1` inside, but I can't make those?

Comment: No, don't store the variable in the function, use .map to find out how many are selected each time it's triggered.

The alternative is to have skills_selected_1 & skills_selected_2 stored outside of the event handlers.

Comment: Note: if you're only ever going to have 2, then skills_selected_1 & skills_selected_2 is probably fine, just not great coding practice. It would be better to have a single event handler that does it all.

Comment: Hmm, okay, I'll do some research on that. I'll have a max of 4 actually, but that will never change. I understand why that isn't best practice if there is a better/cleaner way to do it. I'll research your suggestion and worst case scenario create skillsSelected01 & skillsSelected02, etc.. outside.

Comment: Worst case scenario, yes. But you can just iterate through what is selected in that particular set using $(this).attr('id'); and then mapping the selections based on that id.

Comment: Yes, please post the solution when you get it figured out. I'd like to see it.